# The object is falling and rolling but not rolling to the direction I want and also rolling too much time. How should I solve it?

Tags: c#, unity

The object that fall have a Rigidbody and the Rigidbody settings are: Use Gravity true and Freeze Position only on the X.

The object that falls also has a Sphere Collider Is Trigger false.

The object that falls starts in a box that box has a Box Collider and the Is Trigger is to true.

This screenshot shows the object that falls and roll settings and he is in a box I just disabled the box renderer mesh to see the object inside :

[image: object that fall settings]

And these are the setting for the box the object that falls and rolls is inside :

[image: The box that the object that fall is inside settings]

The problems are :

1. The object falls and when he touches the collider of the box the object starts rolling but to the far direction I want it to roll to the player to the camera direction to roll to the front but it's rolling to the far distance direction instead.

The red arrow is the direction the object roll to its rolling to the forward direction but I want it to roll to the blue direction to the back to my direction :

[image: The directions]

The ARROWS ARE NOT pointing up and down but forward and backward!

2. When the object is rolling it's rolling on a small area between two positions the problem is that it's taking the object to calm down and stop rolling after a lot of time. How can I make it calm down and stop rolling a bit faster?

Comment: Regarding direction, how are you applying your directional force? Are you applying a force through code or tilting the surface it's on? Regarding time rolling, if you want a natural look then you will want to check out [physic materials](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html) to adjust friction. Otherwise, look into applying some code to reduce the object's velocity faster than the physics engine.

Comment: @TimHunter for the direction I didn't do much. No matter if the collider as the surface of the box is rotating or if I change its position the falling is down but the rolling direction is all the time to the forward. Yes I want the natural look and I tried using physic material but not much success so far. I will try the physic material again.  The main goal is when the player opens the box the object should fall down and roll a bit outside then the player picking it up.  I'm stuck now with doing the falling down and the rolling.

Comment: @TimHunter once I added the object that falls a rogodbody and a collider and then on the box set its collider is a trigger to true the object fall and rolling. I didn't add any forces to the object that fall and rolling.

Comment: Sounds like you need to give it a force in the direction you want. In general, if you're looking for a scripted setup like this, then you either need to carefully craft the environment to work with physics (ie. make a slope with a bowl of some kind to catch a moving physics object) or suspend the physics temporarily and use coded movement to get it to move exactly how you want it to before enabling physics again. Otherwise you're likely to face too much unpredictability as the physics engine does it's thing.

Comment: @TimHunter I think you right. Since this falling and rolling is only at this place in the game I better use a script to make it fall and roll rather than start messing around with the physics.  I will try with a script and see how realistic and natural it can get.

Comment: Is this a question related to custom code surrounding the interaction, or an issue with setup in the inspector?

Comment: @Tacoタコス The interaction is fine the box open animation is fine I just want to make the object to look more natural when the box opens the object should fall down and roll a bit outside. The falling and rolling effect is a bit harder to do.